# Can't assign to operator .Multiple assignments in if statement in python

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, variable-assignment, multiple-assignment

The 4th elif ending is throwing an error can't assign to operator.I am trying to design a tic tac toe game and assigning players X and 0 based upon their selection.[can't assign to operator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHehT.png)

```
def player_input(player):
    marker = ''
    while(marker != 'X' and marker != '0'):
        marker = input('{},choose X or 0:'.format(player))

    if(player == 'Player1' and marker == 'X'):
        temp_player1 = 'Player1' and player1_marker = 'X' and temp_player2 = 'Player2' and player2_marker = '0'
    elif(player == 'Player1' and marker == '0'):
        temp_player1 = 'Player1' and player1_marker = '0' and temp_player2 = 'Player2' and player2_marker = 'X'
    elif(player == 'Player2' and marker == 'X'):
        temp_player1 = 'Player1' and player1_marker = '0' and temp_player2 = 'Player2' and player2_marker = 'X'
    elif(player == 'Player2' and marker == '0'):
        temp_player1 = 'Player1' and player1_marker = 'X' and temp_player2 = 'Player2' and player2_marker = '0'
    else:
        pass

    return(temp_player1,player1_marker,temp_player2,player2_marker)
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the and operator in every if statements and replace them with a semicolon ; as and is an operator and it upsets python to assign and to a variable

the corrected code would be :

```
if(player == 'Player1' and marker == 'X'):
    temp_player1 = 'Player1' ;  player1_marker = 'X' ; temp_player2 = 'Player2' ; player2_marker = '0'
elif(player == 'Player1' and marker == '0'):
    temp_player1 = 'Player1' ; player1_marker = '0'; temp_player2 = 'Player2' ; player2_marker = 'X'
elif(player == 'Player2' and marker == 'X'):
    temp_player1 = 'Player1' ; player1_marker = '0' ; temp_player2 = 'Player2' ;player2_marker = 'X'
elif(player == 'Player2' and marker == '0'):
    temp_player1 = 'player1'; player1_marker = 'X' ;temp_player2 = 'Player2'; player2_marker = '0'
else:
    pass
```

Comment: Your python indentation needs fixing

Comment: Thanks for informing

Answer (score 0):

seperate your assignments to different lines:

```
if(player == 'Player1' and marker == 'X'):
    temp_player1 = 'Player1'
    player1_marker = 'X'
    temp_player2 = 'Player2'
    player2_marker = '0'
elif(player == 'Player1' and marker == '0'):
    temp_player1 = 'Player1'
    player1_marker = '0'
    temp_player2 = 'Player2'
    player2_marker = 'X'
elif(player == 'Player2' and marker == 'X'):
    temp_player1 = 'Player1'
    player1_marker = '0'
    temp_player2 = 'Player2'
    player2_marker = 'X'
elif(player == 'Player2' and marker == '0'):
    temp_player1 = 'player1'
    player1_marker = 'X'
    temp_player2 = 'Player2'
    player2_marker = '0'
else:
    pass
```

you should read up on how indentation works in python putting multiple statements in one line is not very common for readability sake

Comment: Thanks for informing